# Refreshing parent activity from child?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

guys, I'm pretty new to java android programming (that's the first app I'm making) and I have this question:
How can i refresh my Main Activity from another activity, which is called from the Main one?
I would also appreciate if you give me some examples, because I'm still not very orientated...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startActivityForResult()` for that purpose, instead of `context.startActivity()` call `context.startActivityForResult()` and then set result in launched activity before finishing it.

Here is the [documentation for `Context.startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Sample code:

```
// Activity A
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_B_FOR_RESULT = 1; // or other int value

    // sample code which starts Activity B
    private void onSomeButtonClick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_B_FOR_RESULT);
    }

    // this method will be called when started activity finished 
    // and returned some result of its work
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_B_FOR_RESULT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // handle result ok and resultData here
            } else {
                // handle result canceled or other resultCode and its resultData here
            }
        }
    }
}


// Activity B
public class ActivityB extends Activity {        

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED); // by default result of starting activity is negative
    }

    // some code which doing some action and setting result as ok
    private void doSomething() {
        Intent resultData = new Intent();
        resultData.putExtra("SOME_EXTRA", "did it"); // or other result data
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultData);
        finish(); // finishing this activity, result code and result data will be accessible in previous activity 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still don't quite understand what to do. Can I give you my code so you can give me some better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

How to call main activity from the sub activity.  Use an interface.

**1. Creata a public interface in the sub-activity**

```
public class MapSettings extends DialogFragment implements
        OnCheckedChangeListener {

     public interface BestRidesSettingsDialogListener {
        void onMapSettingsChange(int mapType);
    }
```

**2. Implement the interface in the main activity** note right click on errors and select add imports add reference add unimplemented methods.

```
public class KmlReader extends ActionBarActivity implements
    BestRidesSettingsDialogListener {
```

**3. when the sub activity starts in the sub activity cast getActivity to the public interface**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // the activity may be null if this is called without implementing the
    // BestRidesSettingsDialogListener (The settings object saves the
    // setting so the
    // call back may not be needed.

    activity = (BestRidesSettingsDialogListener) getActivity();
```

**4. Then in the sub activity when a button is clicked or some event happens call through to the interface method.**

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int checkId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int mapType = 0;
    switch (checkId) {
    case R.id.RDORoad:
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
        break;
    case R.id.RDOHybrid:
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID;
        break;
    case R.id.RDOSatelite:
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE;
        break;
    case R.id.RDOTerrain:
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN;
        break;
    }
    // run the activity onchange
    // if the activity is null there is no listener to take action on the
    // settings
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.onMapSettingsChange(mapType);
    }
```

**5. if you've filled in the unimplemented methods stubs in your main activity your executing code directly in the main activity from the sub activity.**

```
@Override
public void onMapSettingsChange(int mapType) {
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMapType(mapType);
    }
}
```

sidebar for comments:  The interface has always been my favorite part of java.  You might call it a listener or a call back.  Just right click on the errors and select add reference, add unimplemented methods there really are not too many keystrokes to do this.  The interface is perhaps the easiest way to coordinate a team effort on making the next big thing.